# Injecting an HttpClient into a Blazor Component in a Razor class library

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, asp.net-core-5.0

I created a solution from the Blazor WebAssembly template where I checked off the ASP.NET Core hosted checkbox, so I have `Client`, `Server`, `Shared` projects in the solution.

To this solution I added a Razor class library (without checking "Support pages and views") called BlogsRcl in which I have a Blazor component called `Blogs.razor`.

I want to be able to inject an HttpClient into my `Blogs.razor` component just like the `FetchData.razor` component in the 'Client` project has, i.e. '@inject HttpClient Http'.

In the '.csproj' file for my BlogsRcl project I added either/or/both references to

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="5.0.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="5.0.0" />
```

which, everything's kosher with `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`, but when I add `System.Net.Http`, every project in the solution complains that it is `Unable to find package System.Net.Http with version (>= 5.0.0)`.

Yet when I do a Go To Definition on the `HttpClient` in the `FetchData.razor` component in the `Client` project, the metadata says `Assembly System.Net.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.

**Edit:** I tried adding `<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />` too, to no avail.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RCL (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">`) should not need any of those package references as the required ones is part of the framework. In Visual Studio you can see what's included with the framework by expanding `Project/Depedencies/Frameworks/Microsoft.NETCore.App/`.

But you do however have to make sure you also have added the required using directives.
Either add them to the top of your `.razor`-file, or even better for such generic usings, add them to the `_Imports.razor`-file.

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
```

Comment: Man... coulda sworn I added using statements.... Here's a question that no one will ever find useful, lol. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelTranchida Hehe it happens! In your defense - the razor-component editor in VS is really bad and a mistake like this would have easily been catched by the regular .cs editor. Can't wait for the new LSP-based razor editor to become stable enough to be usable...